# RecyclerView textView Listener Like button problems

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

i have a small problem that is driving me crazy
So i'm trying to create a small "social network app" on Android.

In my main fragment i have a RecyclerView that contains the posts (it's like the news feed)
And in each item there's a Like Button and a Comment Button, in the recycler viewAdapter in the onBindViewHolder fonction i use a Volley Request to get all the posts that the user liked and everytime i catch one i set the text color of Like textView (J'aime in French) in blue, like in the image below.

[image: Main fragment with the like buttons in blue]

And if i click on another Like button it becomes blue and the like is added into the database, but the problem is when i want to remove it when i click again it doesn't work in the recycler Adapter i'm checking with an IF Condition if the textview is blue, if it isn't i set the default color and i remove the like from the database, here's the code of the Adapter.

```
package com.example.salim.projet.model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.salim.projet.R;
import com.example.salim.projet.fragments.HomeFragment;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by salim on 24/04/18.
 */

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    int clickedPosition = -1;

    String send_url = "http://10.0.3.2/sendlike.php";
    String drop_url = "http://10.0.3.2/droplike.php";
    String email;
    ArrayList<Likes> arrayLikes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Publication> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Publication> arrayList, String email)
    {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.email = email;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);


        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Context context;
        String likes_url = "http://10.0.3.2/likes.php?email="+email;

        holder.Nom.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNom());
        holder.Prenom.setText(arrayList.get(position).getPrenom());
        holder.Contenu.setText(arrayList.get(position).getContenu());
        holder.Date.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDate());




        holder.Like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickedPosition = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });




        // RECUPERATION LIKES
        // HERE IS WHERE I CATCH ALL THE POSTS THAT THE USER LIKED FROM DATABASE ON A JSON


        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, likes_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                int count = 0;
                while (count < response.length())
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                        Likes like = new Likes(jsonObject.getInt("ID"), jsonObject.getInt("LikeUser"), jsonObject.getInt("PostLiked"));

                        arrayLikes.add(like);
                        count++;


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (!arrayLikes.isEmpty())
                {
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < arrayLikes.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (arrayLikes.get(i).getPost_id() == arrayList.get(position).getId()) {
                            holder.Like.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Like.getContext(), R.color.startblue));
                        }
                    }
                }






//                Log.i("DEBUG", " Position item : " + position + " Position du I : " + i + " ArrayLike Post ID : "+ arrayLikes.get(position).getPost_id() + " ==  Publication ID : " + arrayList.get(position).getId());

//                if (arrayLikes.get(position).getPost_id() == arrayList.get(position).getId()) {
//                    holder.Like.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Like.getContext(), R.color.startblue));
//                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Mysingleton.getInstance(holder.Like.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);


        // FIN RECUP LISTE LIKES








        // HERE IS WHERE I HANDLE THE CLICKS ON THE LIKE BUTTON



        if(clickedPosition == position) {
            if (holder.Like.getCurrentTextColor() == (ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Like.getContext(), R.color.startblue)))
            {
                holder.Like.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Like.getContext(), R.color.defaultt));

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, drop_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("postid", String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getId()));


                        return params;
                    }
                };
                Mysingleton.getInstance(holder.Like.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }

            else
            {
                holder.Like.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.Like.getContext(), R.color.startblue));

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, send_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        params.put("email", email);
                        params.put("postid", String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getId()));


                        return params;
                    }
                };
                Mysingleton.getInstance(holder.Like.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }


        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView Nom, Prenom, Contenu, Date, Like;



        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Nom = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Prenom = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.surName);
            Contenu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feedText);
            Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            Like = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeView);




        }
    }
}
```

All the stuff is happening in the OnBindViewHolder, hope my question was clear, if i can add anything else just tell me and thank you!
Maybe this question may sound weak for you but i'm not a professional and i passed more than 2 days trying to fix this and everytime i get in another problem.

Comment: Split up your logic, calling network from RecyclerView Adapter will make your debugging/testing really hard, and is generally a bad practice due to really coupled code.

Comment: I know, but i couldn't find any other solution to handle the buttons and stuff in specific items of the RecyclerView, i searched a lot here, google etc.. and that's the best i got..